# nameError: name 'pivots' is not defined

Tags: module, global-variables, jupyter

Could you help me to solve the following problem,please ?
I did write a module in python . For the next module I need the following variables or values:
**lastprice and lastpivotprice**

What definition or script change is necessary, that this 2 variables are global variables)?

Actually if i try to call lastpivotprice outside the module i get the following error message:
nameError: name 'pivots' is not defined

Module Code: checkpivots.py

```
    try:  
      df['High'].plot(label='high')

      pivots =[]
      dates = []
      counter = 0
      lastPivot = 0

      Range = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      daterange = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

      for i in df.index:
        currentMax = max(Range , default=0)
        value=round(df["High"][i],2)
        Range=Range[1:9]
        Range.append(value)
        daterange=daterange[1:9]
        daterange.append(i)

      if currentMax == max(Range , default=0):
          counter+=1
      else:
          counter = 0
      if counter ==  5:
          lastPivot=currentMax
          dateloc =Range.index(lastPivot)
          lastDate = daterange[dateloc]

          pivots.append(lastPivot)
          dates.append(lastDate)
   
            
    except Exception:
      print("-")

    lastpivotprice = pivots[-1]
    
    lastprice=df.iloc[-1]['Close'] #read value in the last row in col 'close'
    lastprice2 = df['Close'].values[-2] #read value in the last row minus2 in col 'close'
   
    #print (lastprice)        
    # print (lastpivotprice)
    # print (lastprice2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your variables in every module as globals, you have to set them as global variables. For example see this code below:

```
c = 0 # global variable

def add():
    global c
    c = c + 2 # increment by 2
    print("Inside add():", c)

add()
print("In main:", c)
```

If you delete global from c, the c remains 0 in MAIN.

Comment: Did write global lastpivotprice, but get the same error code.
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\checkpivots.py in <module>
     39 
     40 global lastpivotprice
---> 41 lastpivotprice = pivots[-1]
     42 
     43 

NameError: name 'pivots' is not defined

Comment: This occurs because pivots is a `local variable` in `try block`. You should initialize pivots variable outside the try block. Then in your second file import everything, and call pivots. I will give you an example that works for me to get through to you how this works. You have a module file named test.py
**test.py**
`pivots = []
try:
 pivots.append(1)
 print(pivots)
except Exception:
      print("-")`

In your second py file, you can take pivots list

**test2.py**

`from test import *
print("Pivots are: ")
print(pivots)`